# Sphinxでmakeコマンドを実行するとエラーになる

Tags: sphinx

MacでSphinx (1.6.3)を利用しています。
sphinx-quickstartを実行して、make htmlをしてみましたがエラーが出てしまいます。

```
make html
/usr/bin/python: No module named sphinx.__main__; 'sphinx' is a package and 
cannot be directly executed
make: *** [html] Error 1
```

Pythonは2と3が入っています。
3はHomebrewで入れています。
Sphinxはpip3で入れています。

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

昔別環境で作ったSphinxのプロジェクト配下でのmake htmlは問題なく実行できます。
それがあるので、なぜ今回新しく作ったプロジェクトではエラーになってしまうのかが、よくわかっていない状態です。

Comment: sphinx-quickstart のコマンドパラメータはどのような指定をされていますでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

新しく作ったプロジェクトのMakefileの中身を修正することで問題が解決できることがわかりました。

動作していたプロジェクトのMakefile

```
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
```

新しく作ったプロジェクトのMakefile

```
SPHINXBUILD   = python -msphinx
```

---

私の環境では、pythonコマンドの場合はPython2になります。
なので、下記のようにpython3コマンドで実行できるように書き換えます。

```
SPHINXBUILD   = python3 -msphinx
```

この修正により、make htmlが動作するようになりました。